# Is there a way to calculate a column based on an expression of other columns?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to select a column that's based on the value of other columns. The use case is that I'm interested in intermediate values of a complicated expression.

Something like:

```
SELECT 1.0 as avg, 2.0 as stdev, 100.0*stdev/avg as cv;
```

Is the "right" way to do this using a CTE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to see what went wrong:

```
SELECT 1.0 as avg, 2.0 as stdev, 100.0*stdev/avg as cv;
=# 
ERROR:  column "stdev" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 1.0 as avg, 2.0 as stdev, 100.0*stdev/avg as cv;
```

So, the PostgreSQL error indicates that the `stdev` column does not exist. More precisely/conceptually, there is a logical execution order in which various parts of SQL are evaluated. Here, `stdev` is evaluated at the same time it's defined, which is not OK. It has to be defined prior. Otherwise, it "does not exist" *at this time*.

As you suspected, you can use CTE to force `stdev` to be defined first before use:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1.0 as avg, 2.0 as stdev
)
SELECT t.*, 100.0*stdev/avg as cv FROM t;
```

Or equivalently use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*, 100.0*stdev/avg as cv FROM (
  SELECT 1.0 as avg, 2.0 as stdev
) AS t;
```

(Sub-queries/inner-queries are evaluated before outer queries.)

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use one over the other? Performance, maintainability, etc?

Comment: @ijustlovemath To me, it's just a matter of style. I think CTE is a newer feature. Sub-queries have always been there.

Comment: If you defined this query as a plpgsql script, would this query work by declaring the variables? (Changing AS to INTO)

Comment: @ijustlovemath As far as I know, plpgsql is more like a procedural language (e.g. pascal or C) than pure SQL, although it allows some embedded SQL fragments. You only need it for more advanced things than simple queries like this. Of course, you can use destructive variable assignments (and SELECT INTO) with plpgsql. But it's not pure SQL anymore.